# Couldn't read and show sms in C# Application

Tags: c#, regex, sms, gsm

This is my code for reading incoming messages via a GSM modem. I am using a GSM modem for this application. Message sending works perfectly but when i try to read incoming messages it gives me an error `THERE IS NO MESSAGE`. I think the problem is in my regex. I only want to display SMS (Format doesn't matter).

Here is my code.

```
 ShortMessageCollection messages = new ShortMessageCollection();
        try
        {     
            Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
            Match m = r.Match(input);
            while (m.Success)
            {
                ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
                //msg.Index = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
                msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
                msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
                msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
                msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
                msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
                msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
                messages.Add(msg);

                m = m.NextMatch();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return messages;
```

Comment: input is a simple message which i send from my mobile phone
for example "HELLO. HOW ARE YOU?"

Comment: Have a look at [a fake string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%2bCMGL%3a+(%5cd%2b)%2c%22(.%2b)%22%2c%22(.%2b)%22%2c(.*)%2c%22(.%2b)%22%5cr%5cn(.%2b)%5cr%5cn&i=%2bCMGL%3a+12%2c%223sf%22%2c%22fgh%22%2cjjkkl%2c%22jhj67%22%0d%0atyrtyt5u+rt%0d%0a) that your regex matches now. What is the pattern you need? What are the requirements? Maybe you need to remove `\r\n`s?

Comment: i dont want any regex string my code.so what code should i type instead of this string????

Comment: All i want is just message.

Comment: I am sorry, without knowing what you need... I can just suggest: `ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage(); msg.Message = input; messages.Add(msg); return messages;`.

Comment: its not working kindly edit my regex. i coudnt receive any sms.